# Bash - demostrating the order of substitution

Tags: bash, unix, substitution

I'm trying to demonstrate the order of substitution; mainly that variable substitution, command substitution and globbing occurs in order one after the other.  I executed the following command and I do not get the expected output.

```
bash-4.1$ a=file*
bash-4.1$ ls $(echo $($(b=$a)))
```

I expect the output to list all files names beginning with "file", but instead it outputs the list of all files in the directory.  Any idea why?

Comment: please read: [bash doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)

Answer (score 2):

The `$(...)` command substitution returns the output of the command, which is blank for an assignment. So you simply end up running `ls`.

Comment: Does that mean all 3 substitutions cannot be shown in one line?

Comment: Does `ls $(echo "$a")` work for you? (Note that there are two opportunities for globbing, so I had to turn one of them off.)

Comment: I still get the same results :(

Answer (score 1):

Parameter and arithmetic expansion, and command substitution are evaluated at the same time, leftmost-innermost to right. Assignments, null and empty expansions, and redirects are all valid simple commands. The assignment is lost to the subshell, and the arguments to `echo` expand to nothing. `echo` outputs a newline, but the command substitution strips it, and `ls` gets no args. Also, if you were expecting `a=file*` to do something more than assign a literal string, pathname expansion doesn't occur in assignments.

See: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/grammar/parser_exec

And a challenge question when you figure all that out. What will be the value of `x`? (shows more expansion order and some small Bash quirks.)

```
declare -i x=0
x+=${x:-1} let x+=2 $((x+=4)) {x}<&$((x+=8,0))
```